# numpy count sum of costs for points in same group

Tags: performance, numpy

I have a vector where each point at index i is belong to group vector[i]

```
vector=np.array([[1,1,4,1,4,3,1]])
```

I also have a cost to every point:

```
cost=np.array([[10,10,40,1,4,1,2]])
```

I want to compute in an efficient way without loops the sum of costs for each group, to any point.

For this example i except to get the output:

```
[[23,23,44,23,44,1,23]]
```

for group 1 its 10+10+1+2 = 23

for group 2 its 40+4 = 44 

for group 3 its just 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just:

```
counts = np.bincount(vector, weights=cost)
output = counts[vector]
```

Comment: its cool, but i can't have [[10,10,40,1,4,1,2]] as input , and only
[10,10,40,1,4,1,2] so i will have to use reshape

Comment: @member555 You can use `cost.ravel()` and `vector.ravel()`.

Comment: @member555 oh I thought bincount would flatten the input like so many Numpy functions do. But yeah just use `.ravel()`.